# excel code to print multiple sheets based on formula

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I have to print multiple sheets in excel based on whether that sheet is relevant to a user or not. In a sheet called "Sheet2" I have in column A from cell 14, the sheet names. There are 24 sheets with different names in Column A. In each adjacent cell (in Column B), I have either `True` or `False`. I wish to print the sheets which have a `True` in column B. I am able to print to the sheets one by one and not all the relevant sheets simultaneously as one file.  The code I use is as follows:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim SheetsToPrint As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim sheetWithData As Worksheet
Set sheetWithData = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim startNameRange, endNameRange As Integer
startNameRange = 14
endNameRange = 39

For i = startNameRange To endNameRange Step 1

Dim nameSheetToPrint As String
SheetsToPrint = sheetWithData.Range("A" & i).Value

Dim wsToPrint As Worksheet
Set wsToPrint = wb.Sheets(SheetsToPrint)

If sheetWithData.Cells(i, 2) = "True" Then
    wsToPrint.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
End If



Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us your first attempt.

Comment: Because this is not a free code writing service you will need to start on your own first. Do some re-search and then come back with your code attempt and a *specific* question to it. Also see [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: lol and your first attempt should not be my answer

Comment: Well yeah, that infact is my first attempt. Why would i make a different code when I have a code which is partially working even if its yours. If someone can suggest a further change, great otherwise it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt the vars and try this :

```
Sub PrintSheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim sheetWithData As Worksheet
Set sheetWithData = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Add the first row number and the last row number where start the sheet name
Dim startNameRange, endNameRange As Integer
startNameRange = 2
endNameRange = 4

For i = 2 To 4 Step 1

    Dim nameSheetToPrint As String
    nameSheetToPrint = sheetWithData.Range("A" & i).Value

    Dim wsToPrint As Worksheet
    Set wsToPrint = wb.Sheets(nameSheetToPrint)

    If sheetWithData.Cells(i, 2) = "True" Then
        wsToPrint.PrintOut
    End If



Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works partially since it prints the sheets one by one. I would like to have the sheets printed as one pdf. Thanks for any suggestions.